# Java type promotion in parameters

Tags: java, java-8, type-promotion

I stumbled upon this snippet:

```
public class ParamTest {
    public static void printSum(int a, double b) {
        System.out.println("In intDBL " + (a + b));
    }

    public static void printSum(long a, long b) {
        System.out.println("In long " + (a + b));
    }

    public static void printSum(double a, long b) {
        System.out.println("In doubleLONG " + (a + b));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printSum(1, 2);
    }
}
```

This will result in a compile error:

> Error:(15, 9) java: reference to printSum is ambiguous both method printSum(int,double) in ParamTest and method printSum(long,long) in ParamTest match

How is this ambiguous? Shouldn't only the second parameter be promoted in this case since the first parameter is already an int? The first param need not be promoted in this case right?

The compilation succeeds if I update the code to add another method:

```
public static void printSum(int a, long b) {
    System.out.println(String.format("%s, %s ", a, b));
}
```

Let me expand just to clarify. The code below results in ambiguity:

```
public class ParamTest {

    public static void printSum(int a, double b) {
        System.out.println("In intDBL " + (a + b));
    }

    public static void printSum(long a, long b) {
        System.out.println("In long " + (a + b));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printSum(1, 2);
    }
}
```

Then this code below **also** results in ambiguity:

```
public class ParamTest {

    public static void printSum(int a, double b) {
        System.out.println("In intDBL " + (a + b));
    }

    public static void printSum(double a, long b) {
        System.out.println("In doubleLONG " + (a + b));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printSum(1, 2);
    }
}
```

However this one **does not** result in ambiguity:

```
public class ParamTest {

    public static void printSum(int a, double b) {
        System.out.println("In intDBL " + (a + b));
    }

    public static void printSum(long a, double b) {
        System.out.println("In longDBL " + (a + b));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printSum(1, 2);
    }
}
```

Comment: The compiler can map your call printSum(1, 2); to either printSum(long a, long b) or printSum(int a, double b) hence it is ambiguous. You have to explicitly help the compiler to choose among by giving the type precisely like this: printSum(1, 2d)

Comment: You misquoted the error message, and the difference is very important. The actual error message is: `Error:(15, 9) java: reference to printSum is ambiguous
  both method printSum(int,double) in ParamTest and method printSum(long,long) in ParamTest match` - it's not the method that is ambiguous, it's the call to the method that is ambiguous.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt the error message was from eclipse sorry I misquoted there. anyways, I still don't understand it because adding printSum(int a, long b) removes the error message.

Comment: [JLS-5.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.3) => *If the type of the expression cannot be converted to the type of the parameter by a conversion permitted in a loose invocation context, then a compile-time error occurs.* seems to be applicable to the context, but not really straightforward to infer how. +1

Comment: We definitely need a canonical question for this: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q="15.12.2.5.+Choosing+the+Most+Specific+Method."

Comment: _since the first parameter is already an int_ That's a misunderstanding right there. The first parameter is neither and `int`, `long` or `double`. It's a literal value. That means the compiler is trying to find a method just using the name and then assign the parameter type from the method parameters, not the other way around.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think this has something to do with JLS's specific rule about [15.12.2.5. Choosing the Most Specific Method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5). It states that:

> If more than one member method is both accessible and applicable to a method invocation, it is necessary to choose one to provide the descriptor for the run-time method dispatch. The Java programming language uses the rule that the most specific method is chosen.

How Java chooses the **most specific method** is further explained by the text:

> The informal intuition is that one method is more specific than another if any invocation handled by the first method could be passed on to the other one without a compile-time error. In cases such as an explicitly typed lambda expression argument (§15.27.1) or a variable arity invocation (§15.12.2.4), some flexibility is allowed to adapt one signature to the other.

In the case of your example, all methods are accessible and applicable to method invocation, therefore, Java needs to determine which of them is **most specific**.

For these methods, none can be determined to be more specific:

```
public static void printSum(int a, double b) {
    System.out.println("In intDBL " + (a + b));
} // int, double cannot be passed to long, long or double, long without error

public static void printSum(long a, long b) {
    System.out.println("In long " + (a + b));
} // long , long cannot be passed to int, double or double, long without error

public static void printSum(double a, long b) {
    System.out.println("In doubleLONG " + (a + b));
} // double, long cannot be passed to int, double or long, long without error
```

The fourth method clears ambiguity precisely because it fulfills the necessary condition to be **most specific**.

```
public static void printSum(int a, long b) {
    System.out.println(String.format("%s, %s ", a, b));
}
```

That is, (int, long) can be passed to (int, double), (long, long), or (double, long) without compilation errors.

Comment: So to summerize, if all methods are accessible by the call, then java identify the method, which can be call to other methods without compile time error, if found then use that as most specific and call it otherwise ambiguity error? I think, this one is valid answer @riruzen.

Comment: Thanks! I tried this with (double, int) vs (double, long) and it really did clear up the ambiguity, then (double, int) vs (long, double) was ambiguous as expected.

Answer (score 7):

It is indeed a very interesting question. Let's go through the Java Language Specification step by step.

1. When the compiler is trying to identify potentially applicable methods, the first thing it does is [serching for methods applicable by Strict Invocation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.2).
2. In your case there is no such methods, so the next step is to [find methods applicable by Loose Invocation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.3)
3. At this point all of the methods match, so **the most specific method ([§15.12.2.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5)) is chosen among the methods that are applicable by loose invocation.**

This is a key moment, so let's look at this closely.

> One applicable method m1 is more specific than another applicable
>   method m2, for an invocation with argument expressions e1, ..., ek, if
>   any of the following are true:

*(We are interested in the following case only):*

> - m2 is not generic, and m1 and m2 are applicable by strict or loose invocation, and where m1 has formal parameter types S1, ..., Sn and m2 has formal parameter types T1, ..., Tn, the type Si is more specific than Ti for argument ei for all i (1 ≤ i ≤ n, n = k).

Simply put, a method is more specific if **all of its parameters types are more specific**. And

> A type S is more specific than a type T for any expression if S <: T ([§4.10](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.10)).

Expression `S <: T` means that `S` is a subtype of `T`. For primitives we have the following relationship:

```
double > float > long > int
```

So let's look at your methods and see which one is more specific than others.

```
public static void printSum(int a, double b) {  // method 1
    System.out.println("In intDBL " + (a + b));
}

public static void printSum(double a, long b) { // method 2
    System.out.println("In doubleLONG " + (a + b));
}
```

In this example the first parameter of the method 1 is obviously more specific than the first parameter of the method 2 (if you call them with integer values: `printSum(1, 2)`). **But the second parameter is more specific for the method 2**, because `long < double`. So none of these methods is more specific than another. That's why you have an ambiguity here.

In the following example:

```
public static void printSum(int a, double b) { // method 1
    System.out.println("In intDBL " + (a + b));
}

public static void printSum(long a, double b) { // method 2
    System.out.println("In longDBL " + (a + b));
}
```

the first parameter type of the method 1 is more specific than the one in the method 2, because `int < long` and the second parameter type is the same for both of them, that's why the method 1 is chosen.

Comment: I did not downvote your answer, but this answer does not explain why (int, double) is ambiguous with (long, long) since clearly, (int, double) should be more specific with respect to the first parameter.

Comment: @riruzen it does explain: `double` is not more specific than `long`. And for the method to be chosen all the type parameters must be more specific: *type Si is more specific than Ti for argument ei for all i (1 ≤ i ≤ n, n = k)*

Answer (score 0):

because int value can also be considered as double in java. means `double a = 3` is valid and same with the long `long b = 3` So that's why it is creating a ambiguity.
You call

```
printSum(1, 2);
```

Is confusing for all three methods, because all these three are valid:

```
int a = 1;
double b =1;
long c = 1;
```

You can put the L at the end, to specify that it's long value. for example:

```
printSum(1L, 2L);
```

for double you need to convert it:

```
printSum((double)1, 2L);
```

also read the  @Erwin Bolwidt's comment

Comment: Yes compiler confused for all the 3 methods, first compiler looks for the exact type  and if it doesn't found any then try to find the compatible type, and in this case all are compatible.

Comment: If I have 4 method declarations instead of 3, the ambiguity comes off:
public static void printSum(int a, double b)
**public static void printSum(int a, long b)**
public static void printSum(long a, long b)
public static void printSum(double a, long b)

so while I agree with your answer, it still does not answer the question. Java does automatic type promotion if the exact type is not available if I'm not mistaken. I just don't understand why it becomes ambiguous with those 3.